# Highlight cells a different colour for each number of occurrences of a string

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where we choose what people will be assigned to each job. The job assignment will be on "Sheet" (in my sample spreadsheet). I would like the list of people on the "Pick List" sheet to be highlighted a different colour for every time they are assigned in "Sheet" more than once. I would like one assignment to be green, 2 assignments to be yellow, and 3 or more assignments to be red. I have attached the sample spreadsheet where I have tried a few solutions that are not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zfszLZfGPe0IeXt4yw01VSlERi5vAr0SI3ZektLLAw4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with conditional formatting.

1. On Sheet, select `A1`.
2. Right click and select conditional formatting.
   You will need three rules. They will all be custom formulas (find under format cells if).
3. First enter `=countif(A:A,A:A)=1` in custom formula is. Apply to range should be A1:A. Set formatting style to Green. Click Done.
4. then click add another rule. Custom formula will be `=countif(A:A,A:A)=2`. Apply to same range. Formatting style to Yellow.
5. Add another rule `=countif(A:A,A:A)>=3` for Red.

You really don't need Pick List unless you just want to validate against it. If you do want to validate, you can

1. right click `A1`.
2. choose Data Validation and enter your Pick List range `'Pick List'!A1:A`.
3. Drag `A1` Down in Sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would like to highlight the names in "Pick List" for occurrences in "Sheet" though. I added Sheet! in front of all the A's, but it doesn't seem to be working the same way. I updated the sample spreadsheet - can you please take a look and let me know what I'm missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: To refer to a different sheet in conditional formatting you have to use indirect. The first rule is =countif(indirect("Sheet!A:$A"),A:A)=1 . Adjust the other rules the same way.

Comment: Hi Ed, I'm hoping you can help me one more time... I just applied the conditional formatting to another column and it doesn't work for that one. It is checking column AF in Sheet! for occurrences in column H of PickList!. Is there something that needs to be done to specially reference column AF? The sample spreadsheet is updated to show this. I really appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: See your Sample Sheet.